# screen not setting $TERM to screen

Tags: gnu-screen, terminfo

I have a problem with gnu screen.

Computer 1:

```
open terminal
$ printenv TERM
xterm-color
$ screen
$ printenv TERM
screen
```

Computer 2:

```
open terminal
$ printenv TERM
xterm-color
$ screen
$ printenv TERM
xterm-color
```

Both computers are running Mac OS X 10.6.4, screen version 4.00.03, and similar configuration.

According to `screen` its man page:

> In each window's environment screen
>   opens, the $TERM variable is set to
>   "screen" by default.  But when no
>   description for "screen" is installed
>   in the local termcap or terminfo data
>   base, you set $TERM to - say -
>   "vt100".

In both computers I have the terminfo files for "screen" at `/opt/local/share/terminfo/73`

Even when I do `screen -T screen` I still get the `$TERM` variable set as `xterm-color`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely being overwritten in `~/.bashrc`. That's the case on my system. I added the following line to the top of my `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo $TERM >> /tmp/bashrc.out
```

then started `screen` and did this:

```
$ cat /tmp/bashrc.out
screen
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ grep -n TERM ~/.bashrc
1:echo $TERM >> /tmp/bashrc.out
33:export TERM=xterm-256color
```